# Display variables in Shiny output

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application, where i want to display some user data, to a different page. Here is my UI code

```
home_page <- page("Home page", uiOutput("current_page"), form = 
fluidPage(
 textInput(inputId = "app_name", label="Please enter the name of your application", value="app_x")
))
```

and then i the server i fetch the userinput, and save it inside a varaible, and then display it out again.

```
  output$application_name <- renderText(application_name)
```

but then when i try, to display the variable in a different route, i get this error, when i start up my application.

`Error in page("Read Data", uiOutput("current_page"), content = "This page is used to preproccess data for the given files",  : 
  unused argument (mainPanel(textOutput("application_name")))`

i try to display my variable like this inside my UI

```
                  content = 'This page is used to preproccess data for the given files',

#below i try to output the application name
                  mainPanel(
                    textOutput("application_name")),
                  form = fluidPage( radioButtons("radio", h3("How many files do you wish to add"),
                                                 choices = list("1 File" = 1, "2 Files" = 2),selected = 1),
                                                #select input for single file
                                                conditionalPanel(
                                                condition = "input.radio == 1", 
                                                fluidRow(
                                                  selectInput("select_singlefile", h3("You selected one file"), 
                                                              choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2,
                                                                             "Choice 3" = 3), selected = 1)
                                                        )
                                              ),
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got an issue with your `renderText` where you're not grabbing the user input correctly.  Here's a simple example of how to do that:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

        mainPanel(
            textInput(inputId = "app_name", label="Please enter the name of your application", value="app_x"),
            textOutput("application_name")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$application_name <- renderText(paste(input$app_name))
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```